# Unity Json add and delete

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I have recently started working json in unity. I managed to create a structure that looks like this:

[image]

What I don't understand how to do is:

- how am I supposed to add new elements to the list;
- how can I delete elements from the list.

This is the code that I am using (is still in progress):
[image]

I would be grateful for any kind of suggestions that will help me out on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically add items to a collection do not use an array (`[]`)!

Rather use an adequate collection type which would e.g. be a [**`List`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) especially if you are already calling it list and had this in your code previously ;)

```
public List<PlayerData> playersData = new List<PlayerData>();
```

> **how am I supposed to add new elements to the list?**

```
player.playersData.Add(new PlayerData() 
{ 
    _username = "Example Name",
    _user_ip_address = "123.123.123.123",
    _user_score = 42
});
```

Or even better add a proper constructor:

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public string _username;
    public string _user_ip_address;
    public float _user_score;

    // You need a parameterless constructor for the (de)serialization
    public PlayerData() { } 

    public PlayerData(string name, string ip, float score)
    {
        _username = name;
        _user_ip_address = ip;
        _user_score = score;
    }
}
```

Now it would simply be

```
player.playersData.Add(new PlayerData("Example Name", "123.123.123.123", 42));
```

> **how can I delete elements from the list?**

There are plenty of options for a `List`:

```
// by reference
PlayerData somePlayerData;

player.playersData.Remove(somePlayerData);

// or by index
player.playersData.RemoveAt(index);

// or by range
player.playersData.RemoveRange(startIndex, amount);

// or by condition
player.playersData.RemoveAll(element => element._username.StartsWith("Example"));

// or remove all elements
player.playersData.Clear();
```

---

**Further notes**

1. **Never** use string concat (`+ "/"`) for system file paths!

   Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically inserts the correct path separators according to the device's OS.

   ```
   var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "dropFile.json");
   ```
2. If your goal was that this json is only available for the Unity Editor itself then ok. However, if your goal was that this file is read and written on runtime in the final application then you most probably won't have permissions to directly read/write in the application's installation path.

   → rather use [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)
3. In your `read` method you probably wanted to also convert the loaded data into your field like

   ```
   JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, player);
   ```